# can I customize the background of a polygon in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

Can I customize the background (with an image, for example) with OpenLayers on a polygon?

Thanks for the replies

Comment: where is your polygon coming from?

Comment: Try the answer I have post in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455477/vector-tiles-on-top-of-raster-tiles-is-not-getting-displayed-in-openlayers/46538341#46538341

Answer (score 2):

All WFS / Vector style properties are on http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html
According to that link, you can't set a background image for polygons. Try to do it on the server-side, it's possible with MapServer if you use it.

Comment: The only way I could get it working with Mapserver was via converting to a WMS layer and update the Mapfile to use [symbology](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/examples.html).  See the [hatch example](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/examples.html#example-7-using-the-symbol-type-hatch-new-in-4-6) to draw diagonal lines inside the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, question and answer are old, but no matter.
You can now use in OL 2.13.1 this snippset:

```
var _styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap();
var _ruleDef = [new OpenLayers.Rule({
    symbolizer: {
        externalGraphic: "vertical1.png", //use your bitmap
        graphic: true,
        graphicFormat: "image/png",
    },
    elseFilter: true
})];
_styleMap.styles["default"].addRules(_ruleDef);
yourLayer.styleMap = _styleMap; // put the new StyleMap on your Layer
yourLayer.redraw();
```

The Result should look like:
[image]